# Input-Line masking

Tags: java

I am new to this site, but I was looking for an answer I could not find, so I thought I would ask.  I am attempting to write a java program for a game for individuals to enter in words or phrases, but the other players cannot see what others have typed until the end of the round.  I found a couple things along the lines of this, but an ideal way to implement this would be for the user to be able to see what they are typing until they press enter, and then whatever they typed goes away until the end of the round.  This continues on for the rest of the players.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Console.readPassword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword()) might be what you're looking for.

```
public char[] readPassword()
```

> Reads a password or passphrase from the console with echoing disabled

Or alternatively,

```
public char[] readPassword(String fmt,Object... args)
```

> Provides a formatted prompt, then reads a password or passphrase from the console with echoing disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try java.io.Console.readPassword. You'll have to be running at least Java 6 though.

> /**
>       * Reads a password or passphrase from the console with echoing disabled
>       *
>       * @throws IOError
>       *         If an I/O error occurs.
>       *
>       * @return  A character array containing the password or passphrase read
>       *          from the console, not including any line-termination characters,
>       *          or null if an end of stream has been reached.
>       */
>       public char[] readPassword() {
>           return readPassword("");
>       }

Beware though, [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429) doesn't work with the Eclipse console. You'll have to run the program from a true console/shell/terminal/prompt to be able to test it.